# Android. ListView. Click on child item in View of ListView disables parent OnClickListener

Tags: android, listview, adapter, onclicklistener

Ok, now more extended description.

I have `ListView` element with adapter(extends `BaseAdapter`).
I have 10+ view elements inside `ListView`. Adater working as intended, `onItemClickListener` working good too.

But when inside adapter in `getView` function I'm creating view element for `ListView`, I'm add `TextView` there and set `onClickListener` for this element.

Testing with Toast message shows me that `TextView` `onClickListener` is working. But parent Listener of `ListView` doesn't anymore.

What's the problem? I understand whole concept, but how to ask android do not stop processing click events after `TextView` and do `ListView` click event as well.

I've tried

1. view.performClick();
2. view.callOnClick();
3. view.getRootView.performClick();
4. view.getRootView.callOnClick();

with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
It was wrong to try call 
 `view.performClick();` 
 right answer is 
 assuming that we are in adapter 
 `((ListView)parent).performItemClick(view, position, position)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are binding the click listener with viewgroup of whole item that is not the right way. You need to call addView(textview) and then u can initiate textview click listener only. Also if you are a newbie do use recylcerview instead.

Comment: I'm using recylcerview. I've just don't point this because think that that's not important.<br/> Also i've adding ClickListenere to element, not to all view, like this:<br/> `TextView cell = view.findViewById(mCtx.getResources().getIdentifier("fragment_item_num" + i, "id", mCtx.getPackageName()));`<br/>and adding ClickListener to this